# Causal (Volterra type) differential equation with local Lipschitz condition

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations

Consider the equation
$$
u'(t) = (Fu)(t)
$$
where $F \colon L^2(0,T;\mathbb R^n) \to L^2(0,T;\mathbb R^n)$ is a causal (Volterra type)
nonlinear operator. It means that the value of $(Fu)(t_0)$ depends on values $u(t)$ for $t \in (0,t_0)$.

I need results about solvability of this problem. The book by Gajewski et al.
contains some results when the operator $F$ fulfills Lipschitz condition:
$$
(*)\;\;  \|Fu - Fv\|_{L^2(0,T;\mathbb R^n)} \leq L\|u - v\|_{L^2(0,T;\mathbb R^n)}.
$$

But if $Fu$ contains, for instance, square $u^2$ then it fulfills only
local Lipshitz condition, i.e. $(*)$ is fulfilled only for $u, v \in B(u_0, r)$ where
$B$ is a ball.

Where can I find results for solvability of this equation with local Lipschitz condition?

Comment: $u^2$ does not map $L^2$ to $L^2$. But there is no need to use $L^2$ as a function space. Examine the usual existence proof for ODEs. It is based on converting the ODE to a Volterra equation!

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Thank you. I need $L^2$ space because in my problem Lipschitz condition is fulfilled in $L^2$.